# How to use dojo.query with button?

Tags: javascript, dojo

How can I call dojo.query with button on my page so that I save data in mysql using php?

I need to run the following code on button click:

```
dojo.query("img",dojo.byId("div1")).forEach( function() {
     // this is now the image
     dojo.xhrGet( { url: '/somepage.php',
                    data: { image_name: this.title } // ???: depends on what you want
                    load: function( data ) {
                      alert("I worked!");
                    },
                    error: function( data ) {
                       alert("O NOES!!!");
                    }
                }
    );
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dojo.connect to set up an event listener for the onclick event of the button. If your button has an id of "btn1", the code would be like this:

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId('btn1'), 'onclick', functionNameToRun);
```